# Unable to apply SUPEE-7405 v1.1 to Community Edition 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-7405

I get the following error when trying to apply the patch.

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_CE_1.9.0.1_v1.1-2016-02-23-07-40-19.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 506 (offset 1 line).
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 216.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 538.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php.rej
```

I have tried uploading a fresh copy of lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php from the 1.9.0.1 Magento files but it just shows the exact same error.

Comment: Was `lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php` previously modified ? (like manually, not trough a patch), have you also read all the release details on https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-7405 ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the patch is a find and replace.
Here is what you'll find in the .sh :

```
@@ -216,7 +216,7 @@ class Varien_File_Uploader
         $this->_result = $this->_moveFile($this->_file['tmp_name'], $destinationFile);

         if ($this->_result) {
-            chmod($destinationFile, 0640);
+            chmod($destinationFile, 0666);
             if ($this->_enableFilesDispersion) {
                 $fileName = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/',
                     self::_addDirSeparator($this->_dispretionPath)) . $fileName;
@@ -538,7 +538,7 @@ class Varien_File_Uploader
             $destinationFolder = substr($destinationFolder, 0, -1);
         }

-        if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0750, true))) {
+        if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0777, true))) {
             throw new Exception("Unable to create directory '{$destinationFolder}'.");
         }
         return $this;
```

The lines with the '-' is what the patch will remove.
The lines with the '+' is what the patch will replace.

You'll quickly find where the conflicts are.